# Iterating through an array of Class::Struct objects

Tags: perl

I'm using the [`Class::Struct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct) module
and have two structures, `Cat` and `Kitten`, `Cat` is a mother cat, and one of the attributes of `Cat` should be an array of `Kitten` objects.  I'm having difficulty getting this right.

If I save the `kittens` array as an object I cannot iterate through it as expected; I just get an array with one element which appears to be an array. If I save it as a reference I can not figure out how to deference it correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::Struct;
use Data::Dumper;

struct Cat => [
    name    => '$',
    age     => '$',
    kittens => '$',
];

struct Kitten => [
    name => '$',
    age  => '$',
];

my $lil_kitten = Kitten->new( name => 'Lil Socks', age => 2 );
my $big_kitten = Kitten->new( name => 'Big Socks', age => 3 );
my $old_kitten = Kitten->new( name => 'Old Socks', age => 4 );

my @kitten_array = ( $lil_kitten, $big_kitten, $old_kitten );

my $kitten_count = scalar @kitten_array;
print "There were $kitten_count kittens\n";

foreach my $k ( @kitten_array ) {
    bless $k, 'Kitten';
    print "Kitten: ", $k->name, " is ", $k->age, " years old.\n";
    print Dumper($k), "\n";
}

my $cat = Cat->new( name => 'Socks' );
$cat->age(17);
#$cat->kittens(@kitten_array);
$cat->kittens(\@kitten_array);

my $ref_type = $cat->kittens;
print "Ref type: ", $ref_type, "\n\n\n\n";
#$kitten_count = scalar @$cat->kittens;
#print "There were $kitten_count kittens\n";

print "Once a cat called ", $cat->name, " who was ", $cat->age, "\n";
#foreach my $kat(@$cat->kittens) {
foreach my $kat($cat->kittens) {
    bless $kat, 'Kitten';
    print "Kitten: ", $kat->name, " is ", $kat->age, " years old.\n";
    print Dumper($kat), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should initialize 'kittens' to be an array (using `'@'`) and use curly brackets for precedence in the dereference. I have flagged the changed lines with the comment `# CHANGED`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Class::Struct;
use Data::Dumper;

struct Cat =>
[
    name     => '$',
    age     => '$',
    kittens  => '@',   # CHANGED
];

struct Kitten =>
[
  name     => '$',
  age     => '$',
];

my $lil_kitten = Kitten->new( name => 'Lil Socks', age=> 2);
my $big_kitten = Kitten->new( name => 'Big Socks', age=> 3);
my $old_kitten = Kitten->new( name => 'Old Socks', age=> 4);

my @kitten_array = ($lil_kitten, $big_kitten, $old_kitten);

my $kitten_count = scalar @kitten_array;
print "There were $kitten_count kittens\n";

foreach my $k(@kitten_array) {
  bless $k, 'Kitten';
  print "Kitten: ", $k->name, " is ", $k->age, " years old.\n";
  print Dumper($k), "\n";
}

my $cat = Cat->new( name => 'Socks');
$cat->age(17);
#$cat->kittens(@kitten_array);
$cat->kittens(\@kitten_array);

my $ref_type = $cat->kittens;
print "Ref type: ", $ref_type, "\n\n\n\n";
$kitten_count = scalar @{$cat->kittens};   # CHANGED
print "There were $kitten_count kittens\n";

print "Once a cat called ", $cat->name, " who was ", $cat->age, "\n";

#foreach my $kat(@$cat->kittens) {
foreach my $kat($cat->kittens) {
    bless $kat, 'Kitten';
    print "Kitten: ", $kat->name, " is ", $kat->age, " years old.\n";
    print Dumper($kat), "\n";
}
```

The problem with `@$cat->kittens` is that it first dereferences `$cat` to become an array, then tries to call the method `kittens()` on that array. This involves Perl trying to interpret `@$cat` as a class name by turning it into a string - that is, `scalar @$cat`, which is the size of the array. You end up calling `"3"->kittens()`.